# How to list all app services in google cloud platform using python API

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to write a simple python code to list out the app services in google-cloud-platform ,
In command prompt i'm able to list it by passing the below command

```
gcloud app services list
```

When i searched in stack overflow and other websites i couldn't find any piece of code that can list me app services . Any information related this will be thankful. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is to use the [Admin API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/), for example by making HTTP requests to its REST [`apps.services.list` method](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/reference/rest/v1beta/apps.services/list):

> Lists all the services in the application.
>
> HTTP request
>
> ```
> GET https://appengine.googleapis.com/v1beta/{parent=apps/*}/services
> ```

Or you can always fallback to plain invoking from your python code the same commands that you can run manually and process their outputs, for example via `subprocess.Popen()`.

Answer (score 1):

As you have mentioned that you were unable to find a proper documentation to list out the services or the versions for an application in the Google Cloud Platform, for requests regarding documentation modification you can definitely provide a feedback on the documentation page and we would definitely provide as much information as possible.

Regarding the question, I would have to agree with the previously mentioned solution posted by Mr. Dan Cornilescu, also for further clarification you would be able to call the Admin API that would create a HTTP requests to the REST and provide the [List of services](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/reference/rest/v1beta/apps.services/list) of an application. On the top of that you can also request a call to [List of versions](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/reference/rest/v1beta/apps.services/list) under the service of an application.
[image: Providing Parameters]

Over there if you could provide the requested parameters under the parent section (for your case your application name after 'app/') and execute (at the bottom) the call using your preferred authentication to request the list of services.

[image: Try This App]

You can also click on the icon on the top right corner to able to go to following page where it provides the functions and the method calls in JavaScript. We would try our best to update the calls in Python as well. Thank you so much.

[image: JavaScript API codes]

Comment: This looks like java script API looking  can you help me in finding python API